# Why is the output volume lower on a 1 transistor preamp

Tags: audio

I built the simple common emitter 1 transistor preamp with a 2n3904 from hackaweek (http://hackaweek.com/hacks/?p=327) and hooked it up to my iPod as a test. When I had the small earbuds on my iPods output, the volume was louder than the preamps output. Why is this and why is it called an amp if it attenuates?

Comment: A pre-amp, only prepares a signal for a real amp stage, naturally, hence pre (or "before")

Answer (score 6):

The schematic shows that this is a voltage amplification stage with poor current sourcing ability (that is, not a power amplifier by any stretch). Its output impedance is essentially that of the load resistor R3, and that is 10K. (That is a property of common-emitter amplifier circuits: the load resistor determines the output impedance.)  So it is not going to work well into loads whose impedance is a three digit figure, let alone two digit or single.

The author of the circuit knows this, which is why he calls it a **preamp**.

If you hook it up to headphones, it will not compete with the amplifier in your portable device, which is properly designed to drive their low (typically 32 ohm) impedance.

The earbuds may be "small", but they are hard to drive due to their low impedance: as a load, they are "big".

When an amplifier that has a high output impedance is asked to drive a low impedance load, then most of the signal voltage is dropped across its own output impedance, and only a small part of the voltage is bridged to the load. The output and input impedance essentially form a voltage divider.

Explore using different loads with this circuit. For instance compare the iPod going directly into a PC's audio input, versus through this circuit.

Comment: The bias is not fixed as there is negative feedback.  The bias equation is:  \$I_C = \dfrac{V_+ - V_{BE}}{\frac{R_2}{\beta} + \frac{R_3}{\alpha}}\$.  For \$\beta\$ "large enough", this is quite stable against variation in \$\beta\$ etc.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri I just looked at the schematic again. Base resistor is boostrapped from collector, not from supply, doh! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simplistic explanation: -

It's a bit more complex than this but think about the output being from a potentiometer. The junction of collector and 10k resistor is the wiper; the 10k being the upper part of the pot and the transistor being the lower half of the pot.

To potentially get a large signal out, you want the no-signal mid point of the junction of collector and 10k resistor to be at mid-rail i.e. half Vcc. This is achieved by the transistor acting also like a 10k resistor.

Now, when you apply an input signal, only the transistor can "modify" its resistance - it can go to almost zero resistance and the voltage out will be close to 0V; or it can go to very high resistance (like maybe 1Mohm) and the voltage will rise close to Vcc. But, on average your transistor will "behave" like a 10k resistor with fluctuations up and fluctuations down as the input signal falls and rises.

If you wired your input signal across a 20k potentiometer, set the pot wiper half way and, connected your headphones to the wiper, how much signal would you get into your headphones?

Well, you would get nearly 50% signal if your pot were (say) 5ohms and your headphones were (say) 100ohms. But they aren't.

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

> why is it called an amp if it attenuates?

This requires a response even if it is only indirectly related to your question.

An amplifier can, in fact, attenuate voltage.  This is a good question and goes to the heart of the notion of "amplifier".  From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplifier):

> An electronic amplifier, amplifier, or (informally) amp is an
>   electronic device that increases the power of a signal.

Note that is the *power* of a signal that is increased.  But power is the product of voltage and current.  Thus, it is entirely possible to have an amplifier that has, for example, a *voltage* gain less than 1 (the output voltage is less than the input voltage) but a *power* gain greater than 1.

An example is the c[ommon collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_collector) ([drain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_drain), [anode](http://www.valvewizard.co.uk/accf.html), ...) amplifier, also known as an emitter (source, cathode...) follower.

The voltage gain of this *amplifier* is 1 than one but the *current* gain can be much greater than 1 so the power gain is greater than 1.

As a contrast, consider the [ideal transformer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformer#The_ideal_transformer).  We wouldn't think of calling an ideal transformer an amplifier but, in fact,  a transformer can provide voltage gain or current gain.  But, *it cannot provide both*.  In fact, for an ideal transformer, the input power and output power are equal; the power is neither increased or decreased; it is neither an amplifier or an attenuator.